# Would the professor be annoyed if I failed two grad school applications in previous year?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, recommendation-letter

I applied to two places last year; both failed. I am not sure if I ask the professor to write a letter for me again, would he be annoyed? How should I tell him?

If I tell him that I failed, would that cast a negative impression of me on him?

Comment: The best thing you can do is ask him. We have no way of telling how strangers will act.

Comment: If yes, he is a very bad character.

Comment: Graduate admissions is not an exam.  You can't "fail".  You weren't admitted to the two programs you applied to, but that's not "failure".

Comment: I would view it rather as the institutions you applied to failed to see your talent and drive or that there is a better fit institution for you out there. I am making good progress now with my supervisor and there were some professors in the past who thought I was incompetent. But first impressions are equivalent to judging a book by its cover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two rejections are not so many, especially if you applied to highly competitive universities/departments. [Some](https://www.onlinephdprograms.org/faq/how-many-phd-programs-should-i-apply-to/) suggest applying to as many as 10 different places (of course, assuming you find so many research departments that interest you).

Just ask your professor again, I would not expect him to be annoyed. Even though we cannot know for sure how he will react, the uncertainty about his reaction should not block you from pursuing your academic goals.

Comment: _as many as 10 different places_ — In my experience, 10 is a bit _below average_ for computer science, at least in the US.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt your professor would be annoyed enough to deny you a letter (or several), but you also need to evaluate your plans for advancement. While two applications that aren't successful isn't a large number, and you may have been shooting at too high a target, you may be doing something wrong in your applications.

An application for an academic program, as for a job, needs to show both a suitable background and a strong likelihood of success. If you don't show both of those you won't be successful.

I would ask someone, perhaps your professor, or perhaps some office dedicated to advancing student careers, for advice. Take them everything you have used in your applications and ask them for advice in refining it. Also, as for their advice as to the kind of institution you should be applying to. If you have only applied to Cambridge and MIT and have not been accepted, then you are obviously aiming for too tiny a target. A broader approach is much more likely to be successful. If you have the background and good letters then applying to top universities is probably worth it, but if you apply *only* to such places your chances diminish. Greatly.